# Find a row with a string and paste rows above it

Tags: vba, excel

I'm sorry I have no code - I did some research and couldn't find what I wanted.

I have a table that I want to add rows to with the click of a button.

I created a cell at the bottom which says "End".

I want VBA to copy cells from N15:S16 (two rows), and insert two rows above the "End" cell, along with the pasted data.

How would I go about that in a click function?

Comment: Truly, just try and record a macro that does that... This is REALLY easy. The two things I'd recommend would be to look into `Relative references` (so you can always go above the "End" cell regardless where it is in the sheet) and **NAMING** your cell `End` so you can use it in your code via `Range("End")` kind of constructs... Give it a try and post back some code... We're here to help!

Comment: Thanks John! I will give it a try first thing in the morning :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@John Bustos helped me solve it. I recorded a few macros, and this is the code I have now:

```
Sub Insert_Row_Click()
    Range("T15:AK16").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Application.Goto Reference:="EndCell2"
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
End Sub
```

Have a nice day everyone!

Comment: Wow this is old! I probably couldn't accept it at the time, and then forgot about it. I'll accept it now.

Answer (score 1):

Just curious whether you realise you may not need any code (or formula) for what appears to be your objective (but wanted to post an image so 'as an answer' regardless).

*{In my case using Excel 2007}*

Ensure `N14:S15` is a Table. (Select `N14:S15`, Insert > Tables > Table, do not check `My table has headers` {unless required} and <kbd>OK</kbd>).

In Sheet `Before` I added Table labels and a Total row, in which I added "End" {there is no need for "End"} and added formulae to sum Qty and Value.

With `Before` as a starting point:

[image: SO1697098 example]

`After` is the result of selecting `N14:S15` and pasting that into `N16`.

Comment: Thanks pnuts, but that still requires me to insert rows manually, and I wanted it automatic... because I have some checkboxes and so on.